# GPUImage framework screen recording chain

Tags: ios, ipad, opengl-es-2.0, gpuimage

Within Brad Larson's GPUImage framework, what would be the target chain for a painting app that recorded the screen as a video?

Is it:

GPUImageView -> GPUImageMovie -> GPUImageMovieWriter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as it works out, there isn't an appropriate chain, since there's no GPUImageOutput subclass that generates it's own texture content, without the help of the camera.

I subclassed GPUImageOutput (sort of), with something called GPUImageCanvas. So the finished chain was:

GPUImageCanvas -> GPUImageView -> GPUImageMovieWriter

Hope this helps anyone in a similar position!

Sam